# How structure transform string

Tags: go, struct

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    type TokenType string
    type Token struct {
        Type    TokenType
        Literal string
    }
    const (
        ILLEGAL = "ILLEGAL"
    )
    var example =Token{ILLEGAL,"hello world"}
    fmt.Println(example)
}
```

Can you explain me How ILLEGAL (string) convert to TokenType type? And when and Where does this automated process work? Slicer? Array? Map?

Comment: Type inference refers to the automatic detection of the type of an expression in a formal language https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a struct value using a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) implies assigning the listed values to the fields of the struct value. So it's allowed / valid if the given values are assignable to the struct fields.

[Spec: Assignability:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability)

> A value `x` is assignable to a [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") if one of the following conditions applies:
>
> - [...]
> - `x` is an untyped constant representable by a value of type `T`.

`ILLEGAL` is an untyped string constant which is representable by a value of type `string`, so it is assignable to the field `Token.Type` (of type `string`). During the assignment the untyped constant value will be converted to `string`.